# Computing variance in moving window in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am wondering if there is a tool for calculating variance in a custom size moving window in ArcMap ?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

The standard deviation is the square root of the variance.

You can use the [Focal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm) tool to calculate the standard deviation of your window, then square the result (multiply by itself) using the Times tool or the Raster Calculator to get the variance.

Your [moving window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-spatial-analyst/an-overview-of-neighborhood-classes.htm) can be a square, rectangle, circle, annulus (donut), wedge or a [custom window defined by a kernel file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-spatial-analyst/nbrirregular-class.htm).